# Undo a linux command that has broken my login

Tags: ubuntu, login

I cannot login onto one specific ubuntu account for some reason. I am sure I'm using the correct password. I believe its because of this instruction that I executed yesterday:

**Add pactl upload-sample /usr/share/sounds/gnome/default/alerts/bark.ogg bell.ogg to     the file ~/.xprofile**.

I can still login on my other ubuntu accounts, however.

How can I undo this command and fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can login as root, try this command as root:

```
passwd account
```

Of course, replace account with the user name that you can't use to log in.

If you can't login, then reboot your computer. While it is starting, hold the shift key down. In this way you will reach GRUB if Ubuntu is your only Operating System. If you have more than one OS, then skip this step. Then select the entry with recovery from there and wait. A menu will appear. From there select "Drop to root shell" (Note that the text will not be always like this). Then you will get to the root shell. Enter the command above and if you get any errors, type:

```
mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda2
```

Replace `/dev/sda2` with you root partition. You can see it by typing `df`
Hope it helps!

Comment: If I do that, wont I lose all of my configurations?

Comment: No, you'll just change your password for that account.It won't do anything else

Comment: passwd: changes password for accounts

Comment: mount -o remount,rw : remounts the root filesystem as read-write

Comment: df: shows you the partitions that are mounted. The root partition is /

Comment: I'm glad to help you!